# Copy if not exist in WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I have a config file, myapp.exe.config, that I want to install only if it does not already exist. That is, I don't want to overwrite any existing config file. How can this be done in WiX?

(Ultimately I will have to do something more sophisticated with settings, having defaults and overrides and so on. But in the meantime I am just looking for a short-term fix.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you describe is the default behavior  if the file is the [keypath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003043/what-is-the-wix-keypath-attribute/2003366#2003366) of a component. For example, the following component will not be installed if `foo.config` already exists (or in the case of a versioned file, if a file with a equal or higher version number already exists):

```
<Component Id="foo.config">
   <File Source="foo.config"/>
</Component>
```

Note that if you have multiple files in your component, then only one can be the 
keypath. You can control this by setting the `KeyPath` attribute of the file to `yes`. But the recommended strategy is to have only one file per component, in which case the file automatically becomes the component keypath.

**edit**: note that this default behavior can be overridden with the [REINSTALLMODE property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371182(VS.85).aspx). You may want to open your MSI with [orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557(VS.85).aspx) and see if this property is being set  in the property table.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that I have asked the wrong question. My installer has to be uninstalled before installing a new one. (The tutorial assures me that this is entirely normal for a minor upgrade.) The problem is that the config file is being deleted even if it has been modified by the user. I will have to investigate this.

Answer (score 8):

You want to use NeverOverwrite and Permanent on the component...

```
<Component Id="foo.config.cmp" NeverOverwrite="yes" Permanent="yes" Guid="INSERT_GUID_HERE">
    <File Id="foo.config.file" KeyPath="yes" Source="foo.config"/>
</Component>
```

I use this on my config.json files that contain really long nasty connection strings to a web service.  It should never be blanked out by any user action and linger behind after an uninstall.

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/component.html