# Where are file counts kept?

Tags: c#, windows, installation, wix

When I install an application which has a file `somet.txt` it installs it to a certain location `C:\temp` and windows keeps a register that it has been installed 1 time.

If another application installs the same file with the same id to the same location the install count is incremented to 2.

This is so that if you want to completely remove that file you have to uninstall both applications before the file is removed.

I am looking for the ability to read this count/edit this count/etc.

Does anybody know how to do this, either manually/via wix/via c#?

I found this info

> the installer increments the reference count in the shared DLL registry of the component's key file

Comment: i am quite sure that it's not the OS that does this but the applications themselves. This means there is no standard way of doing what you want

Comment: The applications manage the reference counts for shared files but don't store them. I am wanting to know where this info is at. I presume a registry key, I just cant seem to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files are included in components. The components are referenced in products. The reference count is not stored as a number but the references from products to components is regarded as this count.

To uninstall a component that includes your file, you need to uninstall all products that reference the component.

Comment: That explains the lack of it in the registry. Thanks.

Comment: How to detect the component(s) in which particular existing file "included"? Neither product nor .msi is known.

Comment: @КоеКто That's worth asking its own question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

There are two separate reference counting mechanisms in windows installer, and the other answers each refer to different ones:

1. Components (not files) are reference counted by the number of installed products that refer to them. This requires that the component has the same GUID and [keypath](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGIQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003043/what-is-the-wix-keypath-attribute&ei=EQuxT8v2FYTU-gbUucjYCA&usg=AFQjCNGR565LQNkiHh5s9z1gxt_ji-EDBA&sig2=4-09Z9R-7Ye5Xbb0dnADqg) in the different products that refer to it.
2. There is also a **legacy** `SharedDllRefCount` mechanism which *can* be enabled for the keypath of a component. This does operate on file paths so it will work even if Component GUIDs don't match. However, products are **not required** to properly increment/decrement this reference count, so using this is not recommended. The default behavior in wix is to increment this reference count only if it is already present.

These reference counts are used internally in windows installer: when they both reach zero the component is uninstalled. AFAIK the [Windows Installer API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372860(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't expose this reference count anywhere because there shouldn't be a need for you to read or edit them directly.

Answer (score 2):

The Shared DLL registry is at

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDLLs

If you edit this will invite undefined behaviour.