# More than one files inside the component gives issue

Tags: wix

How do use multiple files inside of the component in WiX?

```
<DirectoryRef Id='v5.0' >
   <Component Id='V5.0Ref' Guid='7c9e6679-83F1-4F22-985B-FDB3C8ABD471'>
     <File Id='SimpleMvvmToolkitCommon.dll' Name='SimpleMvvmToolkit-Common.dll' DiskId='1' Source='Source\Binaries\Silverlight\v5.0\SimpleMvvmToolkit-Common.dll' KeyPath='yes'>
     </File>        
   </Component>
 </DirectoryRef>
```

I am getting an issue when I add more than on file inside of the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding multiple files to a `Component` is just a matter of adding child `File` elements. For example the following adds a `file.txt` to the same `Component` from the same source location:

```
<DirectoryRef Id='v5.0' >
  <Component Id='V5.0Ref' Guid='7c9e6679-83F1-4F22-985B-FDB3C8ABD471'>
    <File Id='SimpleMvvmToolkitCommon.dll' Name='SimpleMvvmToolkit-Common.dll' DiskId='1' Source='Source\Binaries\Silverlight\v5.0\SimpleMvvmToolkit-Common.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
    <File Id='file2.txt' Name='file2.txt' DiskId='1' Source='Source\Binaries\Silverlight\v5.0\file2.txt' />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

It is important to note that only one `File` element can be marked `KeyPath='yes'`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's working now. I reduced a length coding to small piece of code

Comment: This StackOverflow question should answer your KeyPath question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2003043/23852